# What happens when the possible amount of database connections is larger than the PostgreSQL allowed max_connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-connection, puma

**Background:**

On production we have a poorly understood error that occurs sporadically (more frequently by the week) and may take down our whole application at times – or sometimes just all of our background processes. Unfortunately, I am not certain what causes the issue, below is my working theory – could you please validate its logic?

The error preceding the downtime (occurring a couple of hundred times in matters of seconds) is the PostgreSQL error `FATAL: sorry, too many clients already`.

**Working theory:**

Various parts of an API can request connections with the database. In our Ruby on Rails application for example, we have 12 puma workers with 16 threads (12 * 16 = 192 possible db connections). Also, we have 10 background workers, each being allowed a single db connection. If we also account for a single SSH session with 1 database connection, the maximum amount of db connections we would have to anticipate is `192 + 10 + 1 = 203` PostgreSQL connections, set with the `max_connections` in the `postgresql.conf` config file.

Our `max_connections` however is still set to the PostgreSQL default of `100`. My understanding is that this is problematic: when the application thinks more db connections are possible (looking at the application side settings for puma and our background workers) it allows for new db connections to be made. But when those connections with PostgreSQL are initiated, PostgreSQL looks at its own set maximum of 100 connections and breaks the connection.

When instead the amount of "requestable" connections (in this case 203) would either ***be lower than or equal to*** the PostgreSQL `max_connections`, it would utilise the `pool timeout` to queue to requested db connection until a db socket becomes available.

This is desirable since too many connections could be resolved within the pool timeout. Thus the solution to our problem is to make the "requestable" database connections =< possible database connections. If that is still not enough, I should increase the 100 possible connections.

**Does this make sense...?**

Any ideas or criticism would be *very much appreciated!*

Comment: @laurenz-albe, I know that you are very knowledgable about postgresl (I always read your articles and comments with great joy – thank you a lot for them!!!). Could you perhaps share your thoughts on this?

Comment: Part of your question is about Puma's connection pool, which I am not familiar with.  Does it have its own, or does it just inherit something from rails?

Comment: It seems like you already know this, but yes, the error you quote is exactly the answer to your question in the title.

Comment: @jjanes yes, Puma has X amount of workers each with Y threads (and this is indeed a Puma config, not a Rails or PostgreSQL config). This means that my API can serve a max of X * Y requests concurrently, each of which may request a connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your app threads does not need to map 1-1 to database connections. You can use a connection pool for the database connections. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

There is also lots of good info on this subject at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Comment: Thanks again for the articles @dentarg!! It's indeed clear from the ActiveRecord docs that the pool count may lower than the puma thread count. Do you have any ideas on what a proper pool size would be? Since puma threads run concurrently and not in parallel, I can image that setting our pool size to 16 (the amount of puma threads) is not necessarily optimal in terms of performance – perhaps the best possible performance is already achieved with half the pool size.

Comment: I think you need to find out what works best for your setup